# numpy tensordot over multiple axes not equivalent to repeated tensordot?

Tags: python, numpy, tensor

I'm confused about the equivalence of `tensordot` over multiple axes at the same time and consecutive `tensordot`'s.
Consider the following setup:

```
a = [[[1,0],[0,0]],[[0,0],[0,1]]]
b = [[[1,0],[0,1]],[[0,1],[1,0]]]
>>> print(np.tensordot(a,b, axes=(0,0)))
[[[[1,0],[0,1]],[[0,0],[0,0]]],[[[0,0],[0,0]],[[0,1],[1,0]]]]
```

This is all as expected (note that `a` and `b` are the same up to permutation so that it doesn't matter over which axes we contract).
Now, consider this:

```
id2 = [[1,0],[0,1]]
c = np.tensordot(id2, a, axes=0) #tensorproduct of a with identity
>>> np.tensordot(c,b,axes=([1,3],[0,1])) #contract b with identity, and with a
[[[[1,0],[0,0]],[[0,0],[0,1]]],[[[0,1],[0,0]],[[0,0],[1,0]]]]
```

This should give the same output as the first because we only contract additionally with an identity which shouldn't change the output. In fact, as far as I can see, this expression should be equivalent to:

```
np.tensordot(id2,np.tensordot(a,b,axes=(1,0)),axes=(1,0))
```

which *does* give the correct output. So what is going on here? How can I express this last statement using a single tensordot (or einsum)?

edit:
Calculating `np.einsum("ij,klm,jln->ikmn",id2,a,b)` also gives the 'wrong' output